# Polynomial defined by products of binomial coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Consider the polynomial in $x$, 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} {m+k-1 \choose m} x^k , $$
where $m$ and $n$ are positive non-zero integers.

Question: can it be expressed in terms of known function(s) of $x$?

Comment: It would be interesting (and possibly helpful) to know what motivates your Question.  As you define it, each fixed positive integer $m$ will give rise to a family of polynomials with degrees $n=1,2,3,\ldots$.  Checking a few examples might help by ruling out some of the well-known polynomial families.

Comment: The expression is the result of an integral based on a conformal transformation, $x$ is a parameter in the mapping, $m$ and $n$ are Fourier coefficients in the original and mapped domains.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the generic function$$f_{m,n}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} {m+k-1 \choose m} x^k$$ $$f_{m,n}(x)=n\, x \,\, _2F_1(m+1,1-n;2;-x)$$ where appears  the Gaussian or ordinary hypergeometric function (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)).

A few expressions
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 m & f_{m,n}(x) \\
 0 & (x+1)^n-1 \\
 1 & n x (x+1)^{n-1} \\
 2 & \frac{1}{2} n x (x+1)^{n-2} ((n+1) x+2) \\
 3 & \frac{1}{6} n x (x+1)^{n-3} \left((n^2 +3 n +2) x^2+6 (n+1) x+6\right)
  \end{array}
\right)$$ which are just polynomials of degree $n$.

If you define 
$$g_{m,n}(x)=\frac{m!} {n \,x\, (x+1)^{n-m}}\, f_{m,n}(x)=P_{m-1}(x)$$

Comment: The polynomial $P_{m-1}$ can be identified using the identity  (see <a href="http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/17/ShowAll.html">here</a>) $$\, _2F_{1}(a,b;c;z) = 
(1-z)^{c-a-b}  \, _2F_{1}(c-a,c-b;c;z)$$
as 
$$P_{m-1}(x) = m! \, _2F_{1}(1-m,n+1; 2; -x)$$